# I deleted many important data on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, entity

Yesterday, I made some programming errors and as a result many important entity were deleted.
I want to go back for some entities to yesterday.
Can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. Sorry, but you're out of luck there.

Answer (score 1):

In the future test on a separate deploy and backup entities before all new version deploys.